# SQL statement takes over 8 hours to run

Tags: sql

I am doing a query from an SQL database.  The table has over a million records in it.

This is my SQL statement.  It takes over 8 hours to run.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

```
Select 
  Count (userID) as DIBWIZHits, Sum (ssnCount) as SSNs
From 
  tbl_hits10
Where 
 (appName='DIBwiz QMT' or 
  appName like 'DIBwiz-Full%' or 
  appName like 'DIBwiz-Abb%' or 
  appName like 'DIBwiz-Qual%')
  -- or appName like 'DIBwiz%Open%' or appName like 'DIBwiz%Q%')
and 
  lu_date between 
    convert (datetime, '2010-09-01 00:00:00', 102) and 
    convert (datetime, '2010-09-30 23:59:59', 102)
AND 
 (userID<>'888888' and 
  userID<>'999999' and 
  userID<>'777777' and 
  userID<>'666666' and 
  )
```

Comment: Which database engine is this?

Comment: Looks like SQL Server from the `convert (datetime, ..., 102)` bit? Something must be catastrophically wrong with the execution plan or the configuration though. No way should a full table scan on a million records take 8 hours.

Comment: This query may be ugly, but there are no joins or GROUP BY clauses, so it shouldn't be appreciably slower than a table scan. And I can't fathom that a scan on a table of this size would take anywhere within an order of magnitude of 8 hours. Is there something strange about your configuration? Is your table horrendously fragmented? Is it stored on a RAID array of floppies?

Answer (score 4):

I have several pieces of advice for optimization.

1)  You absolutely should be using regular expressions to search for the appname.

2)  You should be comparing the userID to a list, such as "AND (userID not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

3)  Your database table should have indexes.

Each of those should dramatically improve the performance.

Comment: If this is SQL Server (a reasonable assumption given the `convert` function), then:
 1. Definitely not, that would be much slower.
 2. That would not make any difference.
 3. Yes, this should be the first thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

Having the CONVERT(datetime, ...) functions in there where clause will perform that parsing for every row. You would be better off declaring a datetime variable set to the result of the CONVERT and using that. Additionally, using "IN" and "NOT IN" is better than a slew of <>. Finally, LIKE operators with wildcards are generally slower than exact operators.

Comment: The CONVERT will be performed exactly once when building the query plan since it's using constant values. (NOT) IN generates the same plan as a series of AND clauses. LIKE will always be trivially slower simply because it has to do more work, but the real pain comes from having a wildcard at the beginning that prevents the use of an index, which is not the case in this query. (Although I suppose appName could be a huge TEXT column which would bump the cost of his 'stuff%morestuff%' conditions somewhat.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that could be highly platform specific, but I would try to manually break it down in nested queries depending on what indexes are present. E.g. (simplified), assuming there's an index on lu_date:

```
Select Count (userID) as DIBWIZHits, Sum (ssnCount) as SSNs
From 
  (select * from tbl_hits10 
     where lu_date between 
       convert (datetime, '2010-09-01 00:00:00',     102) 
       and convert (datetime, '2010-09-30 23:59:59', 102)
  ) z
Where (appName like 'DIBwiz%' )
AND userID not in ('016266'....)
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN` and `NOT IN`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on your table? If not you should at least add an index to the userID field, don't add an index to the appName field as you are using 'like' it will have no effect.

Given that you have so many records, if you do not already have said index on userID it may also take some time to add the index also but should improve performance a lot.

Comment: Your comment about `LIKE` not benefiting from an index is false, at least in SQL Server 2005.  How Anthony uses `LIKE` (i.e., wildcard at end), he will benefit.  The following post illustrates this - it's easy enough to try for yourself in mgmt studio express (free).  http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on `appName`?

also consider @Detect's suggestion to use `userid not in (< coma_separated_values >)`